# Selecting the inverse of a like statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to know how I can select records from a database to see where the items dont match a certain like statement. This statement doesn't work but it will indicate what i require.

Statement :

```
Select top 1000 * 
from TableName 
where Column7 = 'ColumnValueImWatching'
      and idx6 != like 'Keyword%'
order by ColumnthatIndicatesMostRecentRecords desc
```

How can I construct the like statement to retrieve what I require? It is absolutely required that I use the 'Keyword%' when singling out these records.

Comment: `NOT LIKE '%expression%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For negating output of like use operator **NOT** and place it before like as in your modified code.

```
Select top 1000 * 
from TableName 
where Column7 = 'ColumnValueImWatching'
      and idx6 NOT like 'Keyword%'
order by ColumnthatIndicatesMostRecentRecords desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use NOT LIKE:

```
and idx6 not like 'Keyword%'
```

but you should also decide how to handle null values, so you might have to use this:

```
and (
  idx6 not like 'Keyword%'
  or idx6 is null
)
```

since null is neither `like 'Keyword%'` nor `not like 'Keyword%'`